# How to make C++ not to lose accents while assignment?

Tags: c++, encoding, rtf, ansi

I have a program, that takes an .rtf file, reads it, and then creates a new .rtf file to write there some lines from the first document.

The problem is that it loses non-ascii characters.

The program gets a line from .rtf with `fgetws(strBuff, ...)`, and the line it gets is correct.

But then it does an assignment `strIn = strBuf`, and in strIn we see "u" instead of "ü", "a" instead of "ä", "o" instead of "ö" and "?" instead of "ß" (these are German extensions to the 7-bit ascii standard).

Now can we make C++ not to lose all of this while assignment?

Comment: Please also upload the crystal ball that knows that `strIn` is.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you aren't giving enough information to allow helping you without guessing.

Comment: I internationalized your question a little bit, we know what are "umlaut" and "eszett" but most of the readers don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I've found it. strIn was a CStringA while strBuff was CString. I'm working with C++ the second day so it was a bit tough to solve this simple example. Sorry for not providing enough information, I was working without types too much =__=